# How to move and scale images together

Tags: android, imageview, touch, scale

I want users to be able to scale and zoom two images together while keeping them in their correct relative positions to each other. I do this by using a scale gesture detector on one of the images, then expanding the gesture to the other image. My problem is that, while I can get the images to move together, as soon as I try to scale the second image, the translations get drastically off. Is their something that happens while scaling that I am unaware of? The info.parentPreCoords variable is set at the beginning of the scale gesture detector, before any changes are made to the parent (the base image).

```
int[] childPreCoords = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(childPreCoords);

float[] differencePre = new float[]{-info.parentPreCoords[0] + view.getX(),
                -info.parentPreCoords[1] + view.getY()};


int[] parentPostCoords = new int[2];
info.parent.getLocationInWindow(parentPostCoords);


float[] differencePost = new float[]{info.parent.getX() +
                (scale * (differencePre[0])),
info.parent.getY() +  (scale * differencePre[1])};


view.setScaleX(scale);
view.setScaleY(scale);


view.setX(differencePost[0]);
view.setY(differencePost[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was adding a relative layout container to both of the images and then setting the touch listener on the container. This scaled and transformed both of the images simultaneously.